# How to get last insert id in prolog

Tags: mysql, prolog

I have 2 tables in MySQL. The first table  has already values. Now I want to take the values of the last row and insert them in the 2nd table but I don't know how to write Prolog code for taking the last inserted id. Can you help me? I've tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
connect :- odbc_connect('connect', _,
    [ user(root),
      alias(test1911),
      password(''),
      open(once)
    ]).

fetch(Options) :-
    connect,
       odbc_prepare(test1911, 'select * from test ', [default, default,default], Statement, [fetch(fetch), types([integer, varchar, integer])]),
       odbc_execute(Statement, [id,name,age]),
       odbc_fetch(Statement, Row, last).
```

But I get this error

```
ERROR: Domain error: 'length' expected, found '[default,default,default]'
```

Comment: error apart, seems much inefficient... the query could scan all the table

Comment: In MySQL, there's a `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. But based upon your problem description, it sounds like you're having more general issues talking to the MySQL server?

Comment: I didn't know about this function and i've tried  this code for finding the last insert. 
If i write 'select LAST_INSERT_ID() from test ' this will return the last inserted id and i'll be able to do things?

Comment: If you Google "MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID" you'll find ample documentation how to use it. You don't use it as you suggest. You just say, `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` and it will provide the Id of the last `INSERT` that was performed.

Comment: I wrote "select * from test" and then "select LAST_INSERT_ID()" but the results aren't what i expected. :\

Answer (score 0):

This error is SWI-Prolog ODBC specific. It means the ODBC engine didn't know how to convert some value back to specific type. Experiment with types ([default,default,default]) in your prepare call (string is unconverted /  should work for any type), until you pinpoint the one causing problems.

And perhaps send notice to the author / swi-prolog mailing list which type was problematic (if "mine" wasn't old DBase "decimal saved as string", I'd have sent it ;-)